# Duplicate validation in two selectonemenu in primefaces

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, duplicates, selectonemenu

I have two p:selectOneMenu in a page, both have the same content, the user has to choose two different items, the user cannot choose same item in both selectOneMenu. How do I implement this validation ? My current code is something like this :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="itemOne"
    value="#{backingBean.itemOne}"
    required="true" label="Item One:" requiredMessage="Item one is required!">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.itemList}" var="item" 
            itemLabel="#{item.QLabel}" itemValue="#{item.QLabel}" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu id="itemTwo"
    value="#{backingBean.itemTwo}"
    required="true" label="Item Two:" requiredMessage="Item two is required!">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.itemList}" var="item" 
            itemLabel="#{item.QLabel}" itemValue="#{item.QLabel}" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The first thing came to my mind was to attach a listener in both menus with 'onchange' event, remove already selected item and update the other menu but this seems overkill for such simple task. Is there any other way I can do this ?

Comment: Do you simply not know how to approach the problem or are you looking for an alternative ? Personally speaking, I can't think of another way than what you suggested: Have a listener on both `<p:selectOneMenu>` and have each update the other once a selection is made. You have the option to do it either with or without ajax. Why do you think it's overkill ?

Comment: I am searching for an alternative, it would be great if I could do this by using something like <p:validate ...>